# What does this haskell expression mean

Tags: haskell, lambda, church-encoding

I just started learning about Haskell and I'm trying to use the lambda calculus in Haskell. I found this expression which converts a church numeral to a number but I can't seem to figure out what the 0 in this expression means. I can't find it anywhere:

```
zero = (\f -> \x -> x)
one = (\f -> \x -> f x)
two = (\f -> \x -> f (f x))

getNum church = church (\x-> (x + 1)) 0
```

It's the very last zero that confuses me. Is it the base case or some argument to this lambda expression?

Comment: Church numbers are functions that accept two arguments, and the `church` variable is just such a number. So it is being called with two arguments, one is a lambda expression and the other one is 0.

Comment: Ok, thank you! But the expression (\x-> (x + 1)) only has 1 argument, so when 0 is substituted, this becomes 0 + 1. But how does it work for 5 or so? I still don't quite get it. Is church a predefined thing in the Haskell language?

Comment: Perhaps you could step through what `getNum zero` evaluates to, then `getNum one`, then `getNum two`

Comment: A Church number N accepts two arguments: one is a function `f`, and the other is some other thing `x`. It takes `f` and applies it to `x` N times, so `five f x` is `f(f(f(f(f(x)))))`. `f`itself accepts one argument and returns a result of the same type. So if `x` is a normal integer number, then `f` must be a function that takes and returns integers. If `x` is zero and `f` is a function that adds 1 to its argument, then `five (\x-> (x + 1)) 0` is a function that starts with 0 and adds 1 5 times, which gives us... surprise... 5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the second argument to the "church" function. Church numerals are a way of doing counting in Lambda Calculus. They work in a similar way to Peano numbers. In those you count like this

```
Z = 0
S Z = 1
S S Z = 2
```

Read "Z" as "Zero" and "S" as "Successor". So 1 is the successor of 0, and 2 is the successor of 1. In effect its unary counting.

In Lambda Calculus you only have function application, so you can define 2 as a function that takes an argument "f" and applies it twice.

In your example the Church numbers zero, one and two are defined. Each is a function that takes two arguments. The first argument is the function to apply, and the second is the value to apply it to. The `getnum` function uses the function `succ` (i.e. `\x -> x+1`) which is then applied N times to the base case "0".

You could also define

```
getPeano church = church ('S':) "Z"
```

This will prepend the right number of "S"s to the Z to translate a Church number into a Peano number.

Comment: Oh ok, I see now. Thank you very much for your clear explanation :)